# What is a cheap way to interface a USB keyboard to an Arduino Uno?

Tags: usb

What is the cheapest way to interface a USB 2.0 keyboard to an Arduino Uno?

The keyboard does not support PS/2 emulation (interfacing a PS/2 keyboard to Arduino is easy). So this means the Arduino will read the USB keyboard's keystrokes - whatever their speed of input is.

If it can be solved using an IC then DIP is preferred as it quicker to work  with for soldering and pluggin into breadboard.

Comment: Have you considered USB/UART bridges, like FTDI ones? I might be wrong but lots of them are used in UART communication and other stuff

Comment: Don't it's a bad idea.  Or if you must, use a teensy LC in place of the Uno.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know it possible to do becuase thheres a one chip solution-its here http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/usb-host-board-v2

Comment: but I cant figure out the circuit from that photo-maybe iots based around a max 3421e? teensy LC at its cheapest is a cost of a few arduino Unos-so I dont think its that cheap.

Comment: What to figure out? The description text says: "The USB Host Board is based around the Microchip 24FJ64GB002 microcontroller which contains a built-in full-speed USB host controller".

Comment: @yabbadabba not true. The Teensy LC costs less than an Arduino Uno even before adding the host shield the latter would require, which probably makes the Arduino solution cost three times as much.  If you go unbranded, the microcontrollers are about the same cost, but the Kinetis as used by the Teensy is vastly more capable than the ATmega used on an Uno, and not only in its ability to be a USB host.  Granted, if you go with an unbranded or original board you'll probably need to use something like mbed USB libraries rather than Arduino-type ones.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Im looking ad different ARM CPUs now-which as you imply are about the same cost or cheaper and can handle USB host. Im looking at the  MKL03Z16VFG4 which is about $2 as a solution-but it doesnt look like its in DIP form. So what I need to know now is how to get started using ARM MCU.

Comment: There's hardly any MCU that can handle USB in DIP form.  You'll need to learn new techniques or buy something already on a board.  Not sure the kl03 does USB but the kl25z and similar do.  If it sounds complicated, remember the first thing I said was that the project was a bad idea.

Comment: It is currently totally unclear what the OP's project is, what is the scale of the project, and why there is such a limitation as DIP packaging. So we can't say if this is a bad or good idea.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Here a potentially cheap solution-its USB host implemented in software on ATMEGA 32 -unfortunately they only have driver for mouse not keyboard https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ee476/FinalProjects/s2007/blh36_cdl28_dct23/blh36_cdl28_dct23/

Comment: With V-USB https://www.obdev.at/vusb/ it is possible to bitbang USB 1.1 on Arduino. If ARM MCU in DIP is needed, NXP has some: LPC1114 (M0), LPC1768 (M3)

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way is to get a plain PS/2 (or PS/2-USB convertible) keyboard instead of USB1.1 (I hope you mean the standard LS keyboard, since USB2.0 HS keyboards hardly exist), and interface it to GPIOs in accord with known solutions.

The Arduino Uno is designed around Atmega8u2 and ATmega328P chips, which can act as USB device only, FS and LS. To interface it with a dedicated USB keyboard (which is a USB device), the you need to have the Arduino **as a USB host**. Probably it is possible to emulate some limited hardware host functionality for LS mode (1.5Mbps) over GPIOs, but it will be a remarkable effort.

Comment: For the senario I am interested in I cant switch over to PS/2 unfortunately-as I mentioned in question if it was PS/2 it would be easy to do. I have a guess it can be done with using a single chip that acts as USB host in conjunction with arduino uno.

Comment: You asked for a cheap way. Of course, you can use a dedicated USB host controller based on MAX3421E chip (to SPI), aka "Arduino USB Host Shield", but it will cost you $20-$30, instead of an old junk PS/2 keyboard from some trash.